# Encoding objects for content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

### AngularJS code to Angular 2+ code - Http Issue

I am converting some older AngularJS code (actually its Ionic 1) to newer Angular (Ionic 4) and I have came across an annoying issue.

So on every single Http Post in AngularJS, the previous dev was doing this:

```js
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

// Add authentication headers if required
if (token) headers['x-auth-token'] = token;
if (userid) headers['x-auth-id'] = userid;

var config = {
  url: api(endpoint),
  method: method,
  headers: headers
};

if (method == 'GET') {
  config['params'] = data;
} else {
  config['data'] = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);
}

return $http(config).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});
```

The issue at hand is this line: `$httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);`

In Angular 2+, this does not exists and it is causing issues.

Could someone help me out with converting this to a newer version of Angular?

Here is what I have so far:

```js
let headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
};

if (this.token) headers["x-auth-token"] = this.token;
if (this.userid) headers["x-auth-id"] = this.userid.toString();

let config = {
  url: await this.api(endpoint),
  method: method,
  headers: headers,
  body: data
};

if (method === "GET") {
  config["params"] = data;
  return await this.http.get(config["url"], config).toPromise();
} else {
  config["data"] = await this.formatData(data);
  return await this.http
    .post(config["url"], config["data"], config)
    .toPromise();
}
```

As you can see, I have created this `formatData()` function which tries to serialize the data, but it just doesn't work 100% of the time. Specifically when there is nested JSON data.

Here is the formatData function I created:

```js
async formatData(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj != undefined) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        str.push(
          encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key])
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! If anyone knows of any libraries I can install or anything that is similar to this library: `$httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);`

Comment: Send the data as `application/json`. Don't bother with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: If you must use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use  [jQuery param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to encode the data.

Comment: Yeah so I have to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` due to the backend limitations. So I am trying to make it work using `@angular/common/http` Could you give me an example of converting some nested JSON using jQuery.param?

Comment: @georgeawg please make the jQuery.param comment an answer. I will select a best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created this `formatData()` function which tries to serialize the data, but it just doesn't work 100% of the time. Specifically when there is nested JSON data.

If you must use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use [jQuery param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to encode the data.

```js
console.log($.param({a:88, b:77}));
console.log($.param({a: {b:4,c:8}}));
console.log($.param({a: [4,8]}));
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

There is no formal standard for encoding JavaScript Objects for content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The jQuery library popularized the [param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function as a way to encode objects and arrays. It is understood by some APIs as a [de-facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) standard.

The formal standard for encoding JavaScript objects and arrays is [JSON.org](https://www.json.org) popularized by Douglas Crockford and recognized as standard [RFC8258](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) and ECMA-404.

It is best to use content type `application/json` if possible.